# How to setup gluLookat() and glOrtho() in openGL?

Tags: c, opengl, matrix, transformation, projection

I am new to openGL and have a hard time to understand how to actually parametrize the function gluLookat. I what it does but don't know how to know which parameters I should pass to that function and what consequences it will have.

This is my current code and strangely enough I don't even see the axis I drew... I think it is due to the parameters I pass to the function gluLookAt();

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.0);  /* window color white */
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}


void drawScene(void)
{

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(3.0,3.0,3.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0,1.0,0.0);

//used some random parameters...
gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 0, 1, 0);

//axis
//x
glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
glLineWidth(1.0);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3d(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glVertex3d(1.0,0.0,0.0);
glEnd();

//y
glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
glLineWidth(1.0);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3d(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glVertex3d(1.0,0.0,0.0);
glEnd();

//z
glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
glLineWidth(1.0);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3d(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glVertex3d(1.0,0.0,0.0);
glEnd();
glFlush();
}

void herschaal(){

glViewport(0,0,500,500);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glOrtho(-10, 10, 10, -10, 10, -10);
glLoadIdentity();

}


int main( int argc, char * argv[])
{

glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH );
glutInitWindowPosition(50, 100);
glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
glutCreateWindow("mijn test");
glutReshapeFunc(herschaal);
init();
glutDisplayFunc(drawScene);
glutMainLoop();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most matrix functions (including `gluLookAt`) multiply the current matrix with the matrix that they generate, applying their transformation transformation on top of whatever was already on the stack. So it doesn't make much sense to call `gluLookAt` more than once without a `glLoadIdentity` in between. (Though, it doesn't make much sense to call any of the OpenGL matrix functions anymore, since they're removed from modern OpenGL).

Comment: Have a look at answers here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/41940/how-does-glulookat-work